# ERROR: Bind non-const lvalue reference of type to an rvalue of type

Tags: c++, reference

I have an error that I couldn't solve in my code.

If I call my function in main as the following :

```
Ratio f34(3L,4L);
const Ratio one(f34.divide(f34));
```

or

```
Ratio s = Ratio(7).divide(Ratio(8));
```

I have an error that says

```
   error: cannot
   bind non-const lvalue reference of type ‘Ratio&’ to an
   rvalue of type ‘Ratio’
```

and here is my Ratio constructor and divide function :

```
Ratio::Ratio( long numerator,  long denominator) : nu(numerator) , de(denominator) {
    if (denominator == 0) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Cannot divide by 0");
    }
}

Ratio Ratio::divide(Ratio r) {

        long num = r.de *nu;
        long den = de * r.nu;
        Ratio result(num,den);

        return result;

    }
```

***Note : nu and de are private variables in Ratio class.***

I tried to change divide argument to be ( const Ratio &r ), but that did not solve the problem. I still have the same error.

What I understand is that the compiler complained that he can not make a temporary copy of an object. I still have no idea how can I solve it. I tried every thing!! please help :).

Comment: The compiler-provided Ratio(const Ratio&) constructor is being called.   If you provide one, and trace the call, you'll see this occurring

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) -- the shortest complete program that gives you this error.

Comment: My guess is, `Ratio` has a copy constructor with non-const `Ratio&` argument.

Comment: There's code you didn't post where you write `Ratio &`

Comment: the only place that I have Ratio & is in my copy constructor 

`Ratio(Ratio &obj) = default;
Ratio &operator=(const Ratio &obj) = default;` 

and my ostream overload >>

Comment: @RAA: You need to edit that into your question (presumably as a complete, reduced example).